# Why does $R \in R_p \wedge S \in R_q$ imply $RS \in R_{p+q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following implication. How can I show that it holds true?

> Let $K$ be a commutative ring. For any integer $p$, let $M_p := \{R \in K^{n \times n}: r_{ij} = 0,\ \mathrm{if}\ i > j - p\}$, where $r_{ij}$ denotes the $(i,j)$-th entry of the matrix $R$.
>
> Show that $R \in M_p \wedge S \in M_q \Longrightarrow RS \in M_{p+q}$.

This is a generalization of the known fact (obtained by setting $p = 0$ and $q = 0$) that the product of two upper-triangular matrices is upper-triangular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R \in M_p$ and $S \in M_q$. If $i > j-(p+q)$, then the $i,j$ entry of $RS$ is given by $(RS)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n r_{ik} s_{kj}$; we would like to show that this sum is equal to zero.  Because $R \in M_p$, we will have $r_{ik} = 0$ whenever $i > k - p \iff k < i+p$. Similarly, $s_{kj} = 0$ whenever $k > j - q$.

So, we can rewrite
$$
(RS)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n r_{ik} s_{kj} = \sum_{(j-q)\geq k \geq (i+p)} r_{ik}s_{kj}.
$$
However, if $i > j - (p+q)$, then there are no integers $k$ such that $(j-q)\geq k \geq (i+p)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, could you please elaborate why we would like to show that the sum is equal to zero? The implication doesn't hold true, right?

Comment: Also why there aren't such integers k if $i > j − (p + q)$?

Comment: @philk982 to your first comment: to show that $RS \in R_{p+q}$, we need to show that $(RS)_{ij} = 0$ (when $i > j - (p+q)$).  The entry which must be equal to zero is equal to that sum

Comment: @philk982 to your second comment: if $i > j − (p + q)$, then $(j-q) > (i+p)$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to rename $R_{p+q}$ by $M_{p+q}$ in order to disentangle notations for matrices and matrix spaces. The comments above should be translated accordingly.