# Show that the set of right triangle matrices paired with matrix addition and matrix multiplication forms a zero ring.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $R_p := \{R \in K^{n \times n}: r_{ij} = 0,\ \mathrm{if}\ i > j - p\}$, how to show that the set of right triangle matrices $R_0$ paired with matrix addition and matrix multiplication forms a ring with 1/unital ring?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried so far? What is the definition of "zero ring" which you are using?

Comment: @hasManyStupidQuestions per the first paragraph of [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring), I would guess that a zero ring in this context is a rng of square zero, i.e., a rng in which $xy = 0$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Actually this definition doesn't make the statement to be proved true, so presumably the definition is a bit different

Comment: I actually meant a unital ring.. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show that $R_0$ is a unital ring by applying the [subring test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring#Subring_test).  Clearly, $R_0$ is closed under addition and subtraction. [By your earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3489462/81360), $R_0$ is closed under multiplication.

---

In fact, we can say a bit more: [the inverse of an upper-triangular matrix is upper-triangular](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4841/81360). So, a matrix $M \in R_0$ is a unit of $R_0$ if and only if it is a unit of $K^{n \times n}$.